# How to get fraction in gnuplot label using eps terminal

Tags: gnuplot

Is it at all possible? Is there any way to get fraction in label using eps terminal similar to tex $\frac{A}{B}$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, you can't do that. Why don't you use the `epslatex` terminal?

Comment: I used the epslatex. But then was trying if it was possible.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible. Here is a list of things you can do in the "enhanced" eps terminal

```
set terminal eps enhanced
```

http://www.lns.cornell.edu/~dlr/acceleratorphysics/computing/ps_guide.pdf

But fractions seem not to be there.

Comment: Thanks twin and Christoph. No wonder why I failed to find the solution. Your answers gave me the peace finally!

Answer (score 1):

Let me add another solution *without* `epslatex` or `pdflatex` terminal using enhanced text. The suggestion of @rtomas isn't convincing (at least) on my wxt terminal.

The following suggestion simply uses newline `"\n"` for the fraction with an overprinted and shifted sequence of underscores `\_`.
For convenience, a function is defined which creates the necessary enhanced string.
Both, numbers and strings can be used as argument.
Furthermore, the length of the fraction line is adapted to the longer number (or string) by (mis)using the `sum` function.
You might need to play with spaces at the end to nicely center the arguments.

**Script:** (for some reason works only properly for gnuplot>=5.0.4, July 2016)

```
### mimic \frac{}{} without LaTeX terminal
reset session

frac(a,b) = sprintf("{%s}\n~{%s}{1.4%s}",''.a,''.b,(_s='',sum[_i=1:strlen(''.b)] (_s=_s.'\_',0),_s))

set label 1 at -8,0 font ",40" "@{^2}_{~5{.96\\_}}"    # rtomas' solution

set label 2 at 0,0 center font ",20" frac(1,2)
set label 3 at 3,0 center font ",20" frac(1,234)
set label 4 at 8,0 center font ",20" frac("a^2+b^2     ","(x+1)(x-1)")

plot x
### end of script
```

**Result:** (from wxt terminal)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For simple fractions you can do tricks as:

```
@{^2}_{~5{.96\\_}}
```

which displays the fraction 2/5